# Automatic hyphenation in verbatim text, with guidance

Tags: line-breaking, verbatim, hyphenation

I would like to typeset verbatim text that can have linebreaks on certain text points. I know that `spverbatim` and `listings` can break at spaces, but sometimes this is not enough. Of course, no hyphenation engine can figure out hyphenation points within obscure commands of some programming language, so I am willing to guide the engine with possible break points, say `\?-`. Linebreaks at these break points would need a special hyphenation character, so the reader sees that this is not a break at some space.

A picture is worth a thousand words:
[image]

I am pretty sure I have seen something like that in TeXy looking texts.

**Is there a way to implement such a `\magicverb`?** (Or is it already implemented somewhere?)

<sub>Code for the pic:</sub>

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[margin=1cm]{geometry}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{spverbatim}
\usepackage{listings}
\lstset{language=[LaTeX]TeX,aboveskip=-\ht\strutbox,belowskip=-\ht\strutbox}

\usepackage{dingbat}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\makeatletter
\preto{\@verbatim}{\topsep=0pt \partopsep=0pt }
\makeatother
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\begin{document}
\begingroup
\small
\centering
\begin{tabular}{>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}p{10.8cm}|>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}p{3cm}|}
  approach & output \\
  \midrule
  \verb!\spverb{|\fontfamily{LinuxLibertineO-OsF} \selectfont|}! 
  & \spverb|\fontfamily{LinuxLibertineO-OsF} \selectfont|
  \\
  \addlinespace
\begin{verbatim}
\begin{lstlisting}[breaklines]
\fontfamily{LinuxLibertineO-OsF} \selectfont
\end{lstlisting}
\end{verbatim}
 & 
\begin{lstlisting}[breaklines]
\fontfamily{LinuxLibertineO-OsF} \selectfont
\end{lstlisting} \\
\addlinespace
\begin{verbatim}
\magicverb{\fontfamily{Linux\?-LibertineO-\?-OsF} \select\?-font}
\end{verbatim}
 & \texttt{\textbackslash{}fontfamily\{Linux\carriagereturn{}\hspace{0pt}LibertineO-\carriagereturn{}\hspace{0pt}OsF\}\textbackslash{}select\-font}
\end{tabular}
\endgroup

\bigskip
\noindent{}Of course the last output was faked with
\begin{spverbatim}
\texttt{\textbackslash{}fontfamily\{Linux\carriagereturn{}
\hspace{0pt}LibertineO-\carriagereturn{}
\hspace{0pt}OsF\}\textbackslash{}select\-font}
\end{spverbatim}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Make sure you save this as latin1 not utf8 (or change £ to a single character as understood by pdftex)

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[margin=1cm]{geometry}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{spverbatim}
\usepackage{listings}
\lstset{language=[LaTeX]TeX,aboveskip=-\ht\strutbox,belowskip=-\ht\strutbox}

\usepackage{dingbat}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\makeatletter
\preto{\@verbatim}{\topsep=0pt \partopsep=0pt }
\makeatother
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\begin{document}
\begingroup
\small
\centering
\begin{tabular}{>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}p{10.8cm}|>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}p{3cm}|}
  approach & output \\
  \midrule
  \verb!\spverb{|\fontfamily{LinuxLibertineO-OsF} \selectfont|}! 
  & \spverb|\fontfamily{LinuxLibertineO-OsF} \selectfont|
  \\
  \addlinespace
\begin{verbatim}
\begin{lstlisting}[breaklines]
\fontfamily{LinuxLibertineO-OsF} \selectfont
\end{lstlisting}
\end{verbatim}
 & 
\begin{lstlisting}[breaklines]
\fontfamily{LinuxLibertineO-OsF} \selectfont
\end{lstlisting} \\
\addlinespace
\begin{verbatim}
\magicverb{\fontfamily{Linux\?-LibertineO-\?-OsF} \select\?-font}
\end{verbatim}
 & 
\catcode`\£\active
\def£{\discretionary{\carriagereturn}{}{}}
\begin{verbatim}
\fontfamily{Linux£LibertineO-£OsF} \select£font
\end{verbatim}
\end{tabular}
\endgroup

\bigskip
\noindent{}Of course the last output was faked with
\begin{spverbatim}
\texttt{\textbackslash{}fontfamily\{Linux\carriagereturn{}
\hspace{0pt}LibertineO-\carriagereturn{}
\hspace{0pt}OsF\}\textbackslash{}select\-font}
\end{spverbatim}

\end{document}
```

Comment: It's not so easy to find a suitable character that works with `utf8`, I think I settle with `+`. Thanks.